# Web alternative to Notational Velocity or nvAlt

Tags: macos, web-applications

Has anyone come across a good online alternative to either of these desktop apps? Notational Velocity or nvAlt

The basic feature set:

- full document searching: as fast as possible
- markdown editing and a formatted preview window
- drag and drop documents or links, and convert to markdown
- similar UI system: list of documents with preview of text, large search field

Answer (score 0):

The best alternative to NValt or notational velocity, that I've seen, is [Workflowy](https://workflowy.com/).

It doesn't have many of the features you're looking for, but is definitely worth checking out.